# Stack level too deep while registering on Devise

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, forem

I am currently getting an error while registering with devise. When I press submit on the sign up form, I am redirected to /users with this error:

SystemStackError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create 
stack level too deep

Rails.root: /Users/user/Desktop/Programming/Rails/Site

Request

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"VTOUFUYrYxUD0sJpdCz5Mpn6Dvyf7CVqUjj5oDSIqf8=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"example@gmail.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

I have read other people having similar problems, but none of their solutions have worked.
Here is what I had tried: 
Running a migration, and checking for infinite recursion in routes.rb

Gems:

```
gem 'pg'

gem 'forem', :github => "radar/forem", :branch => "rails4"
gem 'forem-bootstrap', :github => "radar/forem-bootstrap", :branch => "master"

gem 'devise', '3.0.0'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'friendly_id', github: "FriendlyId/friendly_id"
gem 'cancan'

gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"


gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Comment: You may have issues with recursion in your controllers and/or views. Could you either paste your controller and view code, or link to a repository?

Comment: Also, have you tried running `bundle exec rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Can you post your User model.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally happens when you accidentally recursively changing an attribute. If you have a xyz attribute in User model, and a virtual attribute named xyz, that is directly changing the xyz, you end up calling the virtual, the virtual calls the virtual again and so on.. Therefore, take a look on whether something like that happens somewhere in your code.